# How do I get a bound control to report "Empty" when it is bound to emptiness?

Tags: data-binding, windows-phone-7, rss

I'm trying to extend the RSS reader example from [here](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/building-rss-reader-windows).

I've converted the app to panorama. I've made it so that the first panorama item loads with my feeds, and the second item has categories with corresponding checkboxes. The categories are databound to a Categories class, which gets populated from an XML file.

Anyway, the 'my feeds' section which has code that looks like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="ItemName" Text="{Binding ItemTitle}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="ItemDetails" Text="{Binding ItemDetails}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
```

and I'm trying to get it to display "Empty" when there are no feeds in the list (feeds are populated when the checkboxes in the adjacent panel are checked). So I added this code to my OnNavigatedTo method in MainPage.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    this.DataContext = App.Model;
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    // If there are no feeds yet, let the user know
    if (App.Model.FeedItems.Count == 0)
    {
        App.Model.FeedItems.Add(
                    new ViewModel.ItemModel()
                    {
                        ItemDetails = "",
                        ItemTitle = "Empty!",
                        ItemLink = "#"
                    }
                        );
    }
}
```

but that wasn't the right approach. Now if I navigate to another page and come back and there were feeditems in the list, I still get "Empty" followed by the items. How do I fix this?

Also, when the "Empty!" actually works, I am still able to click on the link (ItemLink above); how do I disable the click event for this one case?

Answer (score 0):

In a bit of a coincidence I posted last night about how to extend the ListBox control to have an empty data template. It should be easily extended to something like Panorama or Pivot controls.

The basic theory is that you have a content control with your "No items text" and control the visibility of it and the ListBox depending on whether the ListBox has items.

You can read it at [Extending the WP7 ListBox](http://compiledexperience.com/blog/posts/extending-the-listbox-control).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Nigel's extended ListBox, you have at least a couple of possible solutions:

- Create a [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) embedding your ListBox plus a TextBlock showing the "Empty" text, and make that UserControl toggle the visibility of the ListBox or TextBlock depending on the content of the feeds list.
- Replace your ListBox with a LongListSelector from the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) and set that LongListSelector's ListHeader property to show the "Empty" text when the feeds list is empty.